# Which orbitals of the hydrogen atom are degenerate for n=3?

Tags: orbitals, hydrogen

> 19. Which of the following orbitals are degenerate in the hydrogen atom with $n = 3$?
>       [image]
>       **A**. II and III only;
>       **B**. I and IV only;
>       **C**. I, II, and IV only;
>       **D**. II, III, and IV only;
>       **E**. all.

The answer says its **E**. All of them.

First of all isn't there only 1 electron in hydrogen? And how could the $\mathrm{s}$ orbital be degenerate? Doesn't degenerate mean there are multiple places pairs of orbitals can be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First of all isn't there only 1 electron in hydrogen?

yes

> And how could the s orbital be degenerate? Doesn't degenerate mean there are multiple places pairs of orbitals can be?

"degenerate" means having the same energy.  "Degenerate" refers to a set of orbitals.  It doesn't make sense to say one orbital is degenerate.

Solving the non-relativistic Schrodinger equation, all the orbitals for a given "n" are degenerate.  Energy only depends upon n.

More complete consideration including relativity, spin and quantum electrodynamics shows that they are not all degenerate however.

Comment: What I meant to say was "Doesn't degenerate mean there are multiple places pairs of orbitals can be within the same subshell?" I'm still confused why the answer is all of them. I thought the s orbitals were never degenerate because there is only one place and like you said it doesn't make sense to say one orbital is degenerate. So why is it degenerate? what orbital with n = 3 has the same energy as it? And how do you know?

Comment: If n=3, then l could be l=0 (s), l=1 (p) or l=2 (d).  So when n=3, the degenerate orbitals (according to the non-relativistic Schrodinger equation) are 3s, the three 3p orbitals, and the five 3d orbitals.

Comment: I'm not thrilled about this question, since II and III could easily be a 2p and 1s orbital, respectively. There's nothing to indicate that they're really a 3p and 3s orbital. So my first instinct was choice "B" because I identified the "p" and "s" of a different n than the clearly 3d orbitals.

Comment: I don't like it either, on the one hand the question does  specifically says "n=3", but II looks like 2p, not 3p because 3p would have a radial node http://winter.group.shef.ac.uk/orbitron/AOs/3p/

Comment: Same thing with a 3s.. there would be two radial nodes in a 3s.

Comment: But for 3s, you wouldn't be able to see the nodes in such drawings, in the sense that there is still an outer spherical equal-probability surface.

Comment: Its not an ideal question, I agree, and it is a pity that external examiners did not point this out (assuming its a year 1 exam question),  but presumably at this level the examiners thought that generic orbital diagrams are acceptable.

Comment: is this only valid for Hydrogen? Or for any element is it valid?

Comment: @paracetamol only for hydrogen

Answer (score -1):

The one electron of hydrogen, when excited, reaches 3rd energy level and degeneracy is determined by $(n + l)$, where $n$ - energy level, $l = 0$ for $\mathrm{s}$, $1$ for $\mathrm{p}$, $2$ for $\mathrm{d}$, $3$ for $\mathrm{f}$.

Answer (score -3):

First of all yes there is only 1 e- present in atom of H. But here the atom is "hydrogen like" which can be He+, Li+2 Be3+, etc. The question was twisted at the point n=3, when it said n=3 then the atom can be "hydrogen like" as I mentioned above.

Now n=3 makes the above orbitals with 3s, 3p, 3d and 3f. Now (l) quantum number for **3s=0** for **3p=1**, for **3d=2** and for **3f=3**.

Now, electron can jump in case of **3s=0 to 1, 3p=0 to 3, 3d= 0 to 5 and 3d= 0 to 7**

Thus, we can say that from above orbitals, there will be degeneration in all of them.

Comment: I can make sense of your last two sentences. Are you saying that all orbitals in the third layer are degenerate?

Comment: There are 3f orbitals? That's kind of new to me.

Comment: @Mithoron Just for your information, your edit (i -> I) dequeued the item from the VLQ queue, and the "recommend deletion" never got executed. That's a bummer, isn't it ;)

Answer (score -4):

Ok so the best way to think of this is to compare two atoms. Take for example {Ne} which has 10 electrons so this atom would have a number of n=3. The problem asks what orbitals would be degenerate for n=3 and we know that H has a number of n=1 so this would be just 1s^1 the question is a trick question to make you think that all orbitals above the n=1 orbital are degenerate so really even though it gives you hydrogen its just to throw you off. Picture a n=3 atom for this problem that has no element attached to it in that case all orbitals would be equal energy therefore it would be option E because all orbitals s,p,and d would be degenerate. Hope that helps took my a while to conceptualize this.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry. Feel free to take a [tour]. Visit the [help] for any unanswered questions about the site. I don’t get your answer. But neon’s configuration is $\mathrm{1s^2\ 2s^2\ 2p^8}$, so there is no $n = 3$ in there …